# Help understanding a specific proof of the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability

I have to give a presentation on the proof of the Central Limit Theorem seen here: [image]
which is provided in our book, *Introduction to Mathematical Statistics* (Hogg,Craig).

The problem is that I have to give this presentation before we have covered Normal distributions in class and I think it may take an understanding of them to really understand the CLT. The highlighted parts are the parts that I am struggling with the most, particularly the notation.

It almost seems like this proof says "If we set up these random variables to have the characteristics of a normal distribution, then it will look like they have a normal distribution", which is confusing. I do understand the Taylor series parts, so that's helpful.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: $M$ is known as the *moment generating function*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function

Comment: For the part $M(t;n)$, are you having trouble understanding the function itself, or the notation (particularly the semicolon)?

Comment: I understand that it is the mgf of Y_n, the nth standardized sample mean, but I don't really understand what that means. The Taylor stuff I understand and most of the algebraic work, I just don't understand the variables we're playing with, I guess.